# VBS popup doesn't appear at a specific time using a loop

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBS file with the following code:

```
dtsnow = Now()
hours = Right("00" & Hour(dtsnow), 2)
minutes = Right("00" & Minute(dtsnow), 2)

Do
    If hours > 10 And minutes > 30 Then
        CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Popup "ok", 0, "Window title"
    End If
    WScript.sleep 2000 'every 2 seconds
Loop
```

If I run the file for example at 11:31, the popup is apperaed every 2 seconds, as expected. But if I run the file e.g. at 11:30 i.e. then clock minutes are not more than 30 and then wait a few minutes, the popup doesn't appear when clock minutes are more than 30 while the loop checks the time every 2 seconds.

Why?

Comment: Use the raw values `Hour(dtsnow)` not a formatted string, the `Right("00" & ...` method is purely for padding out values for displaying. Only use raw values like `Hour()` and `Minute()` for computation. At the moment you are trying to compare `"10"` with `10` which will behave unexpectedly.

Comment: @user692942 using raw values doesn't help

Comment: The code in my question worked on computer with Win 7, but doesn't work on Win 10

Comment: Value of hours  and minutes doesn't change within the loop, the code outside the loop should be  moved inside, so that the values change. Nothing to do with windows version.

Comment: @Flakes yes, now it's working. Thanks!